# fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, compiler-errors, pthreads

I'm using macbook and terminal compiling gcc version 4.8.1. I solve some problem like:

```
fatal error ~~~~ No such file or directory
```

by adding such files in compile path myself. As far, those error was resolved by finding in finder application and add in root directory `/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1` myself.

But `pthread.h` does not exist at all my computer.

How can I get that header file?

Comment: GCC 4.8 is kind of old and unsupported. Maybe you should consider a newer compiler. LLVM Clang is often a good choice for OS X machines. Also see [GitHub | build-llvm](https://github.com/noloader/build-llvm).

Comment: The standard gcc way of getting the correct path for `pthread.h` (*and* to get the correct corresponding library) is to use the `-pthread` option on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.1/...  myfile.c -o myfile
```

`-I` indicate gcc to take include file from this specified path.

Comment: sudo apt-get install linux-headers try this it may help :)

Comment: I did sudo brew install linux-headers. But it says brew does not support this